# org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException error while Reading large JSON file in zeppelin scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to read a large JSON file (1.5 GB) using Zeppelin and Scala.

Zeppelin is working on SPARK in local mode installed on Ubuntu OS on a VM with 10 GB RAM. I have alloted 8GB to the spark.executor.memory

My Code is as below

```
val inputFileWeather="/home/shashi/incubator-zeppelin-master/data/ai/weather.json"
val temp=sqlContext.read.json(inputFileWeather)
```

I am getting the following error

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:241)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:225)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:229)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:229)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:171)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:328)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 8):

The error you got is due to a problem in running the Spark interpreter, so Zeppelin could not connect with the interpreter process.

You have to check your logs located in `/PATH/TO/ZEPPELIN/logs/*.out` to know exactly what happening. Perhaps in the interpreter logs you will see an OOM.

I think that 8GB for executor memory on a VM with 10 GB is a unreasonable,(and how many executors are you starting?). You have to consider the driver memeory as well

Answer (score 0):

Increase the driver memory in the pyspark interpreter i.e. spark.driver.memory. By default its 1G